Not able to export data array to nc file
I am trying to export a nc file after regridding but i am facing ValueError while exporting the data. The code is as below and snippet of the error is also attached. The file i am working on is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZkcAEk_jvms3RPmXniEGlW2hpF98J6L/view?usp=sharing
import netCDF4
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
file_path_nc ="D:/Masters/Thesis/Data/NDVI/NDVI_2003_2023.nc"
dataset = xr.open_dataset(file_path_nc)
regrid_lat = np.arange(21.125,31.875,0.25)
regrid_lon = np.arange(76.125,91.875,0.25)
data_array = dataset.interp(lat = regrid_lat,lon=regrid_lon,method='slinear')
NDVI = data_array['NDVI']
output_file = "D:/Masters/Thesis/Data/ReGrid/NDVI.nc"
ds.to_netcdf(output_file)
NDVI.to_netcdf(output_file)


I tried converting it into dataframe and used other method other than xarray. None of them worked.

You should save an xarray.Dataset to nc. Please, see also the source
data_array.to_netcdf(output_file)

Wherease NDVI is xarray.DataArray (taken from DataSet though).
ds variable was not defined at all
